# Visual Studio: how to use scripts to "build solution","rebuild solution", or script instead of clicking the "start" button

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

In my current work, I need to open 3 different solutions, build them and run them.
Is there any script could do the staff as if I click the "build solution", or "start" or "Google Chrome" for Web Service?

Thanks.

Comment: Visual Studio makes use of msbuild which is well documented. If you have that installed then you can use msbuild.

Comment: You'll probably want to go with [msbuild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393574(v=vs.120).aspx).

Comment: Thanks to Irb and Kupiakos, I am going to take a try.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [devenv](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7.aspx). Examples:
**Build**
`devenv mySolution.sln /build Release`

**Rebuild**
`devenv mySolution.sln /rebuild Release`

**Start**
`devenv /run mySolution.sln` or `devenv /run myProject.csproj`